# Address in registration form Magento 1.8.1

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, customer-address

I install 2 different extensions to add address in registration form.

The issue that appears in both is that when I change country, The states do not refresh and continue showing us states.

I think is a theme problem.

Here is the `register.phtml` code:

```
 public function getRegion()
    {
        if (false !== ($region = $this->getFormData()->getRegion())) {
            return $region;
        } else if (false !== ($region = $this->getFormData()->getRegionId())) {
            return $region;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The identity of the 2 different extensions would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the address to show with no new features, then technically you do not need to install an extension for this.

Simply create a local.xml file with the following snippet of code:

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields"><some_value>true</some_value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Another thing to check is if the extensions add any custom js or template that could mess up the update of the regions.

Comment: create local.xml file where?

Comment: @ErdemEce in your theme